# How to convert array in following format

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having following multidimensional array. I want to convert this array in new array form as given in array 2

Array-1

Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => PRpriyer
        [1] => job1232
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => PRpriyer
        [1] => job1234
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => PRpriyer
        [1] => job1235
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => PRpriyer
        [1] => job1236
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => JSjais
        [1] => job1232
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => JSjais
        [1] => job1234
    )
```

)

I want new array from this format, like this: 
Array-2

Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => PRpriyer
        [1] => job1232 | job1234 | job1235 | job1236
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => JSjais
        [1] => job1232 | job1234
    )
```

)

How to convert? Please help

Comment: Use array_unique function.Simple and sweet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($array1 as $value){   $tmparray[$value[0]][]=$value[1]; }
foreach($tmparray as $key=>$values){   
  $result[]=array($key,implode(" | ",$values)); 
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

$array1 is the original

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $value){

   $newArray[$value[0]] .= $value[1]." | ";

}
```

newArray:

```
Array
(
    [PRpriyer] => job1232 | job1234 | job1235 | job1236 | 
    [JSjais] => job1232 | job1234 | 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following:

```
function convertArray($inputArray) {
    $array = array();
    foreach ($inputArray as $value) {
        $array[$value[0]][] = $value[1];
   }

    $returnArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
        $returnArray[] = array($key, implode(" | ", $values));
    }
    return $returnArray;
}

$result = convertArray($inputArray);
print_r($result);
```